# Zenoss time based monitoring

Tags: zenoss

We use Zenoss for system monitoring and few backup servers will use 100% of NIC bandwidth from 17:00 to 22:00 everyday.

I hope there is a setting to allow me to setup different threshold for different time period but did not find any.

Does Zenoss support this feature ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to write something that [Maintenance Windows](http://wiki.zenoss.org/Maintenance_Windows) won't cover?

Comment: I don't think I can add maintenance window for a single interface. We still want to monitor other resources but just don't want the NIC high utilization alerts caused by backups.

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall there is no direct way to do this in zenoss. But i found this interesting zenpack. I haven't tested it yet but the description appears to be relevant to what you ask, which is time based threshold values.

Please have a look here:

http://wiki.zenoss.org/ZenPack:Duration_Threshold

let me know if it works.

Comment: That looks promising but I am not sure the syntax for every day from 17:00 to 22:00 using Zenoss time operators. Any chance you know how to write that ? Because what I need is to be able to specify the start and end time, not just a duration.

Comment: I checked all the zenpacks (which is the easiest way), community and commercial and could not find one that can match your requirement. I found some useful information for you though. Look at the link http://wiki.zenoss.org/Transforms_Tip:_Transforms_based_on_Time . Basically this example tells you how to drop an event between a specified time for a specific device. I think a little bit of tweaking could help you acheive what you need. You can read more about event transforms here which can help you get started: http://wiki.zenoss.org/Event_Transforms_and_Examples

Answer (score 1):

You can write/edit event transformation, which will drop your high NIC utilization events for selected devices and selected network interfaces during defined time window. It's not nice (it's hardcoded) and flexible solution, but it should work.